# Is the `standard` tag a good one?

Tags: discussion, tags

I encountered the [standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard) and am wondering if it's remotely a good idea. It seems to imply *any* standard... should it exist? or perhaps should we disallow it and encourage people to specify the standard they're asking about ANSI, ISO, POSIX, LSB, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, the tag of [standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard) seems kind of useless. It would make more sense to have the actual names of standards as tags rather than this high level tag.

Answer (score 3):

While there are many unix-related standards, by default, “standard” in a unix context refers to the POSIX/Single Unix standard family. When it doesn't, other tags should guide towards the applicable standard.

I think the  [standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard) tag is useful because quite a few askers don't know what standards apply in a given situation. [standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard) is a perfectly reasonable tag for questions such as [How stable are Unix shell "stdin/stdout APIs"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42056/how-stable-are-unix-shell-stdin-stdout-apis), [Which are the standard commands available in every Linux based distribution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37064/which-are-the-standard-commands-available-in-every-linux-based-distribution), [What is not shell specific?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20538/what-is-not-shell-specific), …